# Replace value of a column if the value of another column is a duplicate

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that contains three columns: ID, name and date. The name column is not unique and may contain duplicates. I want to change the date of the duplicated name to the earliest date. For example:

Input:

```
id  name    date
1   Rachel  3/10/2020
2   Dave    1/5/2020
3   Rachel  1/10/2020
4   Rachel  1/1/2020
5   Jason   4/15/2020
6   Dave    7/1/2020
```

Output:

```
id  name    date
1   Rachel  1/1/2020
2   Dave    1/5/2020
3   Rachel  1/1/2020
4   Rachel  1/1/2020
5   Jason   4/15/2020
6   Dave    1/5/2020
```

In the sample data above, there are three dates associated to Rachel, the earliest date is 1/1/2020, therefore, in the output, all the dates associated to Rachel are changed to 1/1/2020.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cleaner way would be:

```
df["date"] = df.groupby("name").date.transform("min")
```

Outputs:

[image]

Comment: This works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
# step 1, create minimum date dataframe
df_min = df[["name", "date"]].groupby("name").min().reset_index() 
# step 2, get new dates in a joined df
df_joined = df.join(df_min.set_index("name"), rsuffix="_r", on="name")
# step 3, cleanup
df_result = df_joined[["id","name","date_r"]]
df_result.columns = ["id","name","date"]
df_result
```

|  | id | name | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Rachel | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | Dave | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 3 | Rachel | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 4 | Rachel | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 5 | Jason | 2020-04-15 00:00:00 |
| 5 | 6 | Dave | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 |

**Done!**

---

Details:

Assuming your dataframe has a lot of records and is given as:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": ["3/10/2020", "1/5/2020", "1/10/2020", "1/1/2020", "4/15/2020", "7/1/2020"],
        "id": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
        "name": ["Rachel", "Dave", "Rachel", "Rachel", "Jason", "Dave"], 
    }
)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%m/%d/%Y") # only needed if dates are given as string, change format according to your dates
```

|  | date | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-03-10 00:00:00 | 1 | Rachel |
| 1 | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 | 2 | Dave |
| 2 | 2020-01-10 00:00:00 | 3 | Rachel |
| 3 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 4 | Rachel |
| 4 | 2020-04-15 00:00:00 | 5 | Jason |
| 5 | 2020-07-01 00:00:00 | 6 | Dave |

1. From the original dataframe, you can create a new dataframe containing names and minimum dates

```py
df_joined = df.join(df_min.set_index("name"), rsuffix="_r", on="name")
```

|  | name | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Dave | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 |
| 1 | Jason | 2020-04-15 00:00:00 |
| 2 | Rachel | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |

2. Then you can join these two to get the minimum date from the new df:

```py
df_joined = df.join(df_min.set_index("name"), rsuffix="_new", on="name")
```

|  | date | id | name | date_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-03-10 00:00:00 | 1 | Rachel | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 | 2 | Dave | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2020-01-10 00:00:00 | 3 | Rachel | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 4 | Rachel | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 2020-04-15 00:00:00 | 5 | Jason | 2020-04-15 00:00:00 |
| 5 | 2020-07-01 00:00:00 | 6 | Dave | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 |

3. Cleanup

```py
df_result = df_joined[["id","name","date_new"]]
df_result.columns = ["id","name","date"]
```

|  | id | name | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Rachel | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | Dave | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 3 | Rachel | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 4 | Rachel | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 5 | Jason | 2020-04-15 00:00:00 |
| 5 | 6 | Dave | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 |

Comment: Thanks! It's a valid solution but the other answer is cleaner.