# How to make duplicates unique in a DataFrame robustly?

Tags: dataset, pandas, dataframe, duplicate

I have the following table.

I was able  to parse it and display it as a DataFrame with **pandas** in python

I need to change the Ref for every value that is duplicate such that it becomes unique.

For example Ref column would become B1-C1 / B2-C1 / B3-C1 / B4-C1 / ... / B1-C2 / B2-C2 / .. / B1-C3 / B2-C3 etc.

I already read **[this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/87009/replace-value-of-a-column-if-the-value-of-another-column-is-a-duplicate?newreg=3147e21a073c46c58b0a6e3712cf776f)** to identify if a row is a duplicate by `Ref`

I thought about creating a subset of C1's then C2's and so on and then relabelling inside the subset.

Is there a way to do this quicker and more robustly?

```
# Ref     Val                     Package                                                      PosX       PosY       Rot  Side
C1        2.2uF                   C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               36.4500    45.0750   90.0000  top   
C1        2.2uF                   C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               60.0500    45.0750   90.0000  top
C1        2.2uF                   C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               12.8500    63.8750   90.0000  top
C1        2.2uF                   C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               24.6500    63.8750   90.0000  top
C1        2.2uF                   C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               36.4500    63.8750   90.0000  top
C1        2.2uF                   C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               71.8500    26.2750   90.0000  top
C1        2.2uF                   C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               12.8500     7.4750   90.0000  top
C1        2.2uF                   C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               24.6500     7.4750   90.0000  top
C1        2.2uF                   C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               71.8500     7.4750   90.0000  top
C1        2.2uF                   C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               48.2500    45.0750   90.0000  top
C1        2.2uF                   C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               12.8500    45.0750   90.0000  top
C1        2.2uF                   C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               48.2500    63.8750   90.0000  top
C1        2.2uF                   C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               60.0500    26.2750   90.0000  top
C1        2.2uF                   C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               48.2500    26.2750   90.0000  top
C1        2.2uF                   C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               71.8500    63.8750   90.0000  top
C2        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               35.6500    51.6750    0.0000  top
C2        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               59.2500    32.8750    0.0000  top
C2        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               47.4500    51.6750    0.0000  top
C2        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               12.0500    70.4750    0.0000  top
C2        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               35.6500    14.0750    0.0000  top
C2        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               12.0500    14.0750    0.0000  top
C2        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               47.4500    14.0750    0.0000  top
C2        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               59.2500    51.6750    0.0000  top
C2        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               23.8500    14.0750    0.0000  top
C2        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               35.6500    32.8750    0.0000  top
C3        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               75.0000     7.4750   90.0000  top
C3        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               39.6000     7.4750   90.0000  top
C3        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               51.4000     7.4750   90.0000  top
C3        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               27.8000    26.2750   90.0000  top
C3        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               63.2000    63.8750   90.0000  top
C3        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               75.0000    45.0750   90.0000  top
C3        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               16.0000    26.2750   90.0000  top
C3        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               63.2000     7.4750   90.0000  top
C3        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               39.6000    63.8750   90.0000  top
C3        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               27.8000    63.8750   90.0000  top
C3        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               16.0000    63.8750   90.0000  top
C3        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               51.4000    63.8750   90.0000  top
C3        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               16.0000    45.0750   90.0000  top
C3        10uF                    C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.08x0.95mm_HandSolder               16.0000     7.4750   90.0000  top
C4        1uF                     C_0402_1005Metric_Pad0.74x0.62mm_HandSolder               75.1550    59.7500  -90.0000  top
C4        1uF                     C_0402_1005Metric_Pad0.74x0.62mm_HandSolder
```